# MSTest - data drive ntest from a method?

Tags: mstest

Anyonw knows how? There is a way to put in a data source, but what is the syntax to have the data injected from a amethod?

I need to test all classes with specific attributes. The test basically validates certain attributes in certain assemblies (checking whether the database is in sync).

For that it would be nieto use one data driven test htat has a "driver" method that feeds in the names or types of the classes to test.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the DataSourceAttribute http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.aspx

Comment: Ah - no ;) See, that does not allow one to put the data source into a METHOD. Which is explicitly what I asked for.

Comment: what you can do with the DataSourceAttribute is to map your data source like [DataSource("System.Data.OleDb",
           "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\"C:\\sample.mdb\"", "Table1",